# CrudRepository filter for String value in List<String> property

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, data-access-layer

basically I got following entity (extended by Lombok)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity("FOO")
public class Foo{

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
     private long id;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name = "FK_FEE", nullable = false)
     private Fee fee;

     @Column(name = "CCCS")
     @Convert(converter = StringListConverter.class)
     private List<String> cccs;
}
```

And the StringListConverter:

```
@Converter
public class StringListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final List<String> list) {
        String returnValue = null;
        if (list != null) {
            final List<String> trimmedList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (final String strg : list) {
                if (strg != null && !strg.isEmpty()) {
                    trimmedList.add(strg.trim());
                }
            }
            returnValue = String.join(",", trimmedList);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(final String joined) {
        List<String> returnValue = null;
        if (joined != null) {
            returnValue = new ArrayList<>();
            final String[] splitted = joined.split(",");
            for (final String strg : splitted) {
                if (strg != null && !strg.isEmpty()) {
                    returnValue.add(strg.trim());
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

And now I want to fetch a List of `Foo` where `Fee.Id`= 123 and `Foo.cccs` contains a specific string value.

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
    List<Foo> findByFeeIdAndCccsIn(Long feeId,  String ccc);
}
```

But this does not work. Is the only way to solve this by writing an own query?

Comment: `findByFeeIdAndCccsContaining(Long feeId,  String ccc);` I think it's something like that

Comment: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List FooRepository.findByFeeIdAndCccsContaining(java.lang.Long,java.lang.String)! unknown collection expression type...

Comment: Yes... never tested it with converted cols. It seems that you'll have to write a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it seems the only solution is to use `@Query` and write a JPQL or native SQL query to get the data.

```
String SELECT_BY_FEE_AND_CCC = "Select foo FROM Foo foo "
        + " WHERE foo.fee.id = :feeId AND foo.cccs LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', :ccc) ,'%')";
```

and attached with the `@Query` annotation like:

```
@Query(SELECT_BY_FEE_AND_CCC)
List<Foo> findByFeeIdAndCccsContains(@Param("feeId") Long feeId, @Param("ccc") String ccc);
```

NOTE/EDIT:
Sometimes you have to join the foreign table to have access on it's properties.

```
String SELECT_BY_FEE_AND_CCC = "Select foo FROM Foo foo "
        + " JOIN foo.fee fee "
        + " WHERE fee.id = :feeId AND foo.cccs LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', :ccc) ,'%')";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends CrudRepository<Foo, Long> {
        @Query( "Select foo FROM Foo foo WHERE foo.fee.id = :feeId AND foo.cccs LIKE CONCAT(CONCAT('%', :cccs) ,'%')")
        List<Foo> findByFeeIdAndCccsIn(@Param("feeId") Long feeId,@Param("cccs") String ccc);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> And now I want to fetch a List of Foo where Fee.Id= 123 and Foo.cccs
>   contains a specific string value.

You have specific requirements. According to [Spring Data JPA doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) what you are trying to do is not supported.

So you should use `@Query` for your requirements.